# Spring Security Configuration anyRequest().authenticated() not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

My understanding of spring security's configuration `http.anyRequest().authenticated()` is that any request must be authenticated otherwise my Spring app will return a 401 response.

Unfortunately my spring app does not behave this way, but lets unauthenticated requests pass through.

This is my Spring Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .antMatcher("/*")
                .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/index.html")
                .antMatchers("/error")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources");
    }
}
```

The AuthenticationTokenFilter takes a JWT token from the request, checks its validity, creates an Authentication from it, and sets the authentication in the SecurityContextHolder. If no token is provided, the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() remains null.

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reports")
@Slf4j
public class ReportController {

    @RequestMapping()
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getIds() {
        log.info(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

}
```

When running a curl request against the endpoint without a token, I simply get a valid response:

```
-> curl 'localhost:8080/reports/'
[]
```

When debugging, I can see that the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It actually works as expected and that is due how you have written your configuration.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .antMatcher("/*")
                .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

This is your own configuration, with some additional indentation by me. When you write an `antMatcher` here that means everything following that `antMatcher` applies to the path/expression written in there (see the Javadoc of [`AntPathMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)).

Now as you have written `/*` this applies to `/reports` it doesn't apply to `/reports/` (yes that last `/` matters!).

What you probably intended to write is

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .antMatcher("/**")
                .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Notice the `/**` instead of `/*`. However that basically is the same as leaving out the `antMatcher` and simply writing

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Can you give explanation to my qn as well :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894199/explanation-regarding-spring-security-url-based-security/55894749#55894749